# RxJava , best way to network check before each api call

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava for my network calls and before each request I need to check the network. 
Currently for each request I'm doing like this.

```
             checkNetwork()
            .andThen(netWorkCall())
            .subscribe(new DisposableSubscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + t.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
                }
            });
          }


            private Completable checkNetwork() {
                return NetworkUtils.isConnected() ? Completable.complete() : Completable.error(new Throwable("Network Error"));
            }

            private Flowable<String> netWorkCall() {
                return Flowable.just("Api response");
            }
```

Is this the recommended way or is there any better way than this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: why do you need to check for the network? if there is no connection, an error will arises and you can manage it inside `onError`

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't check the network before. Better try to send the call and catch the errors when the request failed.

In your Repository which query the network you can prevalidate for a connection and throw an exception if the network connection failed.

That means:

```
networkCall()
  .subscribe( 
    success -> { ... }, 
    error -> { doSomethingWhenErrorHappened() }
   );

private Flowable<String> netWorkCall() {
     return networkAvailable() ? Flowable.just(...) : Flowable.error(...);          
}
```

Thats the way it goes.

You should consider using a `Single` or `Maybe` since a network request usually returns only data onec or an error. Flowable is designed for using a stream.

Comment: but if I have _n_ number of network calls , everywhere I have to repeat 
`networkAvailable() ? Flowable.just(...) : Flowable.error(...);` this rite?

Comment: Usually you dont check for network. You just send the call. It will throw an error if no network connection is available anyway.

Comment: Okay, forget network call, for any other usecase which has to be done before every request!

Comment: `andThen` is not recommended?

Comment: Its not how you do network calls. You just do the network call and dont care about connected or not using functional developing (or reactive). If will throw an error if not.